# Restrict viewport selection of a bone

Tags: bones, outliner

Is there a faster way to restrict viewport selection of a bone than navigating through armature hierarchy in the outliner and pressing the corresponding button next to the bone? It can be a bit cumbersome to go through the entire hierarchy if you have a lot of bones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bone layers and bone groups, to speed up navigation, selection and visibility (in pose mode).

[image]